# Food imports and exports from Turkey

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, food-and-drink, turkey

I am travelling to Turkey and would like to know if are there any laws/regulations regarding bringing food into or out of Turkey?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there always are customs laws.

> ### Free import:
>
> - 1kg of coffee; 1kg of instant coffee; 500g of tea; 1kg of chocolate; 1kg food made of sugar;
>
> **Prohibited**
>
> - Meat and dairy products

---

> ### Free export:
>
> - Local drinks and foodstuffs up to a total value of TRY 100, each commodity not to exceed 5 kgs
>
> **Prohibited**
>
> - Grain products
> - Tea
> - Cacao
> - Coffee
> - Spices

[Source](https://turkey.visahq.com/customs/#!export-regulations)

Comment: Many tourists visiting Istanbul's egyptian bazaar buy some spices there. I doubt that they manage to eat 500g or 1kg of cinnamon by the time they flight back home.